# sed looses right part of the line

Tags: unix, sed

I have some difficulties with the sed command on Unix AIX IBM). It's seems also on linux...

here is a line of my file, that i would change :

```
# id=<$IdEDFRGB.RR '" fgg t uj67575 uj:$ g re ee >
```

it should be after the subsitution :

```
# id=<$Id22 02 21 17:13$  g re ee >f rgrge
```

when i use this sed command (after initialize the DT variable) :

```
sed "s/<\$Id.*\$/<\$Id${DT}\$/g"
```

I obtain :

```
# id=<$Id22 02 2021 17:41$
```

I loose the right part.
Someone could help me ?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `echo ".*\$"`, you will see `.*$`, the pattern matches any text up to the string end, that's why your "right side" is eaten up. `$` in a double quoted string is used to expand variables and in order to use a literal `$`, you need to use a `"\$"` char combination. In order to introduce a `\$` *literal text* into a double quoted string, you need `"\\$"`.

Use single quotes to avoid these issues, only use double quotes around the variable:

```sh
sed 's/\(<\$Id\).*\(\$\)/\1'"$DT"'\2/' file
```

Here, `\(<\$Id\)` is a capturing group 1 (`\1`) that captures `<$Id` literal text and `\(\$\)` is a capturing group 2 (`\2`) that captures a `$` char. The `$DT` is within double quotes and is expanded correctly.

Using capturing groups, you avoid having to double the literal text both inside the pattern and the replacement.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the backslashes in the regexp so they're treated as literal backslash by the shell's string parser, and then they will escape the `$` in the regexp. You also need to escape the `$` in the regexp so that they don't start a variable expansion.

```
sed "s/<\\\$Id.*\\\$/<\$Id${DT}\$/g"
```

Comment: No the backslashes  are to avoid interpretation of the '$'

Comment: Backslashes are needed at two levels: to prevent interpretation as starting a variable by the shell, and to prevent interpretation as a regexp operator by `sed`.